# How can we check if MVC view is partial or not in solution explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an existing Asp.net  MVC 4 project and I want to know if there is any way to check in solution explorer that if view is partial or not. Please suggest.

Comment: if (this.ControllerContext.IsChildAction)
        {
          
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partials often have an underscore prefix in their name. Other than that, nothing really separates them from other views.